# How to handle StaleElementReferenceException when verifying a text?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a set of common methods which I run for each test. Like I need to add a few items in my cart and the whole test runs for each item. But for the first item it runs fine and when the process is repeated for the second item it fails while verifying a text and I get a `StaleElementReferenceException`.

How do I look up the item again or solve this ? Thanks.

Code where it fails:

```
public bool VerifyItemPresentInCart()
{
        //Get the cartsize and verify if one item present
        IWebElement cartSize = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='cart-size']>div"));                                             
        string actualMsg = cartSize.Text;
        string expectedMsg = "1";
        VerifyIfTextPresentMethod(expectedMsg,actualMsg);                
        return true;                  
}
```

Error at

```
  IWebElement cartSize = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='cart-size']>div"));
```

Update: html code

```
  <a class="header-button show-cart has-cart-items" data-view-name="cart-badge" data-view-cid="view5" data-model-cid="c6" data-tappable="true">
   Cart
   <div class="cart-size">
     <div>3</div>
   </div>
```

New code:

```
   IWebElement cardDetails = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='form-field clear-fix']>label[for='cardNumber']>div"));
```

Comment: I presume the error occurs on the line with `cartSize.Text`? I'm not sure why you would be getting a `StaleElementReferenceException` as this is generally in situations where you have got a handle on an element prior to a refresh or major action and then attempt to use the old element handle.

Comment: @Nashibukasan, The error occurs when finding the element. I tried using refresh and deleting the cookies but still shows this exception. when I comment out these four lines the test runs fine without any errors. I think the element is not attached to the DOM or has changed. I want to know how to look up the element again.

Comment: Your code should be getting the element each time it is calling `FindElement`. See my answer below to possible solutions. Maybe also provide the target HTML as perhaps there is a better way to access the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try joining your lines of code:

```
IWebElement cartSize = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='cart-size']>div"));                                                        
string actualMsg = cartSize.Text;
```

So that they are:

```
string actualMsg = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='cart-size']>div")).Text;
```

This means that the text will be retrieved on the element as it is selected. I am wondering if between getting a handle on the element via its parent and retrieving the text you are losing focus on that element. Alternatively, remove the `>div` from your css and see if it retrieves the text anyway.

This not working suggests the situation you are facing is the point under the title [The Element is not Attached to the DOM](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp). The fact that your target text is within only divs suggests that this area is being styled by javascript and thus may only be active at certain times. If this element is not active, but is accessible, you can still receive the `StaleElementReferenceException`, as indicated at that page. Your next step would be to see if you can click a parenting div to activate this target div prior to accessing its text (eg. make sure the element is attached to the DOM then call the code you have provided).

Comment: sorry tried your code. it still shows the same error. Tried removing div too.

Comment: Awesome Thanks alot. It worked when I added a parenting div to it. That was very simple. But I have a similar problem with another line which i have updated in the code. This line works fine for first two tests, for the third time when it comes to the line it says unable to locate element. But the same was visible for the first two times.

Comment: why is that .. a element is visible first two times but not the third. as you said i added the parenting div to this one too.

Comment: If you are using a 3rd party javascript library (such as Kendo) sometimes the HTML is not what it seems. For Selenium to work everytime you must find the element that the user is interacting with when they are using the application with a conventional mouse/keyboard. It is possible there is some javascript at play and it is only making the 3rd line visible after the first two?

Comment: I use the Firebug in FF to get the HTML code. Does this have the same problem too. What do you recommend then, from where should I get the html code?

Comment: So how to find the element that the user is interacting with when they are using the application with a conventional mouse/keyboard?

Comment: Try different parent elements until it works generally! Attributes to look at are those like 'visible' or 'enabled'. It's not a matter of how you are getting the elements via debugging tools, it's that you are targeting the correct elements. I use chrome and find the element in the Developer Tools, then I interact with the element with the mouse while watching the changes in the HTML. That generally provides the best hints.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Will try to find element as you suggested.